# Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible while Invoking

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I have my service configured as below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:808/service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:808/service/"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"   />

      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="net.tcp" binding="netTcpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyEndpointBehaviour">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and the client as:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService1" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1/service/" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService1" contract="IService1"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/MachineName" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

When using WCFTestClient or SVCutil, I am able to discover and access the servie and generate proxy or stubs.

But when I want to invoke any of the methods getting following error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The **service is offline** or **inaccessible**; the **client-side configuration does not match the proxy**; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
>
> **The socket connection was aborted.** This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:04:59.9980468'.

Comment: How long do the server methods take to execute?

Comment: @DanielKelley, with in fraction of a second I get the error . The moment I click on Invoke, get this error

Answer (score 2):

Set the following value inside the endpoint block

```
<identity>
   <dns value ="localhost"/>
</identity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but for development on the local machine I always use an HTTP endpoint. I find Net.TCP will only play nice when it is hosted on a server in IIS.

It is easy enough to add the NET.TCP endpoints once you deploy to an IIS server. Note: that the base address no longer has any affect as that is set in IIS. To test the new endpoints it is best to start by opening the service in a browser while remoted into the server, that way you get the best error messages.

If i understand correctly you are trying to select the endpoint when creating the service reference? Thats now how it works.
If you create your service reference using  `127.0.0.1/service/Service1.svc`

You should see in your config file something like the following. (When I create my service endpoints I always name them with the protocol as a suffix.

```
        <endpoint address="http://servername:8090/servername/servername.svc/Business"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BusinessHTTP"
              contract="servername.IService" name="BusinessHTTP" />
       <endpoint address="net.tcp://servername:8030/Service/Service.svc/Business"
              binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BusinessTCP"
              contract="servername.IService" name="BusinessTCP" />
```

then in your code you can choose which endpoint to use.

```
Dim svc as New SeviceReferenceName.BusinessClient("BusinessTCP")"
```

Comment: Thanks, Doing exactly the samething. Hosted my service on IIS and by browsing service shows the metadata and WSDL . Just unsure why the problem while invoing

Comment: did you generate the proxy from the IIS installation? What port does IIS expose your service on?

Comment: I have deployed the app on IIS, but the generating the proxy using net.tcp endpoint. Do I answer correctly? What I mean to say , I dont want to use the http://127.0.0.1/service/Service1.svc (though it's accessible using browser) instead I want to use the end point

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. It was the issue of port address of **EndpointAddress**. In Visual studio port address of your file (e.g. Service1.svc) and port address of your wcf project must be the same which you gives into **EndpointAddress**. Let me describe you this solution in detail which worked for me.

There are two steps to check the port addresses.

1. In your WCF Project right click to your Service file (e.g. Service1.svc) -> than select **View in browser** now in your browser you have url like **http://localhost:61122/Service1.svc**   so now note down your port address **as a 61122**
2. Right click your wcf project -> than select **Properties** -> go to the **Web Tab** -> Now in **Servers section** -> select **Use Visual Studio Development Server** -> select **Specific Port** and give the port address which we have earlier find from our Service1.svc service. That is **(61122)**.

Earlier, I had a different port address. After specifying the port address properly, which I got from the first step, **EndpointAddress 61122**, my problem was solved.

I hope this might be solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

NetTcp binding is secured by default.In the security authentication process between client and service,WCF ensures that the identity of service matches the values of this element. Therefore service need to be configured with :

```
<identity>
   <dns value ="localhost"/>
</identity>
```