# WCF error: Failed to invoke the service

Tags: wcf, azure, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

This is my model 2 tables `idAlu` is PK in `Alumno` and FK in `Calf`...

*Alumno*

```
idAlu    (PK)
nombre
apePat
```

*Calf*

```
idAlu        (FK)
aprobadas
reprobadas
activo
```

[Screenshot Of Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdEDQ.png)

My code is...

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    frapuccinoEntities fe = new frapuccinoEntities();

    public List<Alumno> list()
    {
        List<Alumno> list = fe.Alumno.ToList();

        return list;
    }
}
```

Simple list, but I get this error...

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible

`web.config` is for default, not binding added.

```
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: To improve the Quality of your Question, please reproduce your table structure as text in the question rather than just as a picture.  Pictures are hosted off-site and the link to them can break.  Also, the text tables are easier to read, and copying information from then when preparing an Answer is sometimes useful.  You may use a link to an image of the tables *as well*, but the text-in-the-Question option is preferred.  Also, images are still useful for presenting information that can not readily be reproduced as text in the Question.

Comment: @Zac Mazk take a look at this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610041/failed-to-invoke-the-service-possible-causes-the-service-is-offline-or-inacces. Could be similar to your issue.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Look at my answer here and it may help you troubleshoot your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902643/cant-activate-wcf-service/10902740#10902740